# How to check if data returned from ajax as json is empty object or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have set this script for checking if the email address exists in the DB or not:

```
function checkemail(){
            var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
            if(e != ""){
                document.getElementById("emailstatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
                $.ajax({
                    type:'get',
                    url:'{!! URL::to('checkEmailExists') !!}',
                    data:{'email':e},
                    success:function(data){
                        // console.log(data);

                        if(Object.keys(data).length === 0)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("emailstatus").style.color = "red";
                            document.getElementById("emailstatus").innerHTML = e + " is NOT OK";
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById("emailstatus").style.color = "green";
                            document.getElementById("emailstatus").innerHTML = e + " is OK";
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

So the code works fine but the only problem is comes from this condition checking which always returns *TRUE*:

```
if(Object.keys(data).length === 0)
```

Basically, if I enter an email address that **does not exist** in the DB, this will be returned as `data` (results of `console.log(data)`):

```
{}
```

Otherwise, it will return this obj:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Myname",
    "email": "myemail@yahoo.com",
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "created_at": "2022-02-09T05:49:27.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-02-09T05:49:27.000000Z"
}
```

So I need to properly check if the returned object is empty or not.

But it looks like that `if(Object.keys(data).length === 0)` is not correctly checking that condition since it always *TRUE* & therefore the `[email] is OK` statement appears on page.

So how to properly check if the returned object is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys should work:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I suggest you double-check the params sent to the `success` function.

Comment: It returns alwayse *TRUE* even if the returned object is `{}`

Comment: Couldn't you just do `Object.keys().length > 0`?

Comment: @nagidi It doesn't return 0 if there are keys. Check your params again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a specific property, if it's not there then it will be `undefined`, meaning you didn't get a success response.

Combine `undefined` with `||` to get a "value if not set", gives:

```
success:function(data) {
    var success = (data.id || 0) > 0;
```

You could just check for `if (data.id == undefined)` but there are a number of caveats when comparing with `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

See below solution that have worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { par1: value1, 
                par2: value2 },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(response) 
                 {                                     
                   if(Object.keys(response).length > 0) 
                   {
                     //there is valid returned response    
                   }
                    else
                    {
                      //no response keys returned                            
                    }
                },
                error: function (x, h, r) {
                    //deal with errors....
                }
            })
```